# Flex 3 Using an image as a border

Tags: css, apache-flex, actionscript-3

I am working on an custom container and I need a border for this container. I have a 15x15 image that I am creating a 9-slice border skin with. The issue that I am having is that the border skin does not appear the way that I had hoped it would.

Here is a ss of the skin in place. 
[image]

Ideally I should have a transparent box with a 5 pixel border around it.

Here is my current testing code:

CSS Code:

```
Box
 {
borderSkin: Embed(source="15x15.png",
            scaleGridLeft="5",
            scaleGridTop="5",
            scaleGridRight="10",
            scaleGridBottom="10");
 }
```

MXML Code:

```
<mx:WindowedApplication xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute">
<mx:Style source="MainTest.css"/>

<mx:Box id="tw" width="400" height="400">

</mx:Box>
</mx:WindowedApplication>
```

Comment: This looks correct. Your png is in fact 15x15 pixels right? have you tried adding a mimeType?

Comment: I have a similar (or the same) problem. I set the border-skin of an HBox with an embedded image (no scaling), but for some reason the image is used to fill the background.

Comment: Just to echo @quoo -- I suspect your image is smaller than 15x15

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
Box{
    background-image: Embed("15x15.png",
       scaleGridTop="5", 
                   scaleGridBottom="10", 
                   scaleGridLeft="5", 
                   scaleGridRight="10");

    background-size:"100%";
}
```